# Access an object with the keys in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I want to access this:

`obj['example']['example-2']['example-3'];`

problem is I have an array where I store those keys:

`arr = ['example', 'example-2', 'example-3'];`

but this array can be of variable length so maybe it's just 3 keys maybe there are 6.
How can I achieve this without hardcoding each case, for example:

```
if(arr.length == 1){
  //obj[arr[0]];
}else if (arr.length == 2){
  //obj[arr[0]][arr[1]];
}
```

etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the path and reduce the object.

```js
function getValue(o, path) {
    return path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return (o || {})[k];
    }, o);
}

var obj = { example: { 'example-2': { 'example-3': 42 } } },
    arr = ['example', 'example-2', 'example-3'];

console.log(getValue(obj, arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

For other people, if you didn't want to use reduce you could use a simple for loop.

```js
function getNestedValue(obj, keys) {
  var ret = obj[keys[0]];
  for (var i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) {
    ret = ret[keys[i]];
  }
  return ret;
}

var ob = {
  HelloWorld: {
    James: {
      Ted: 55
    }
  }
};
var depth = ["HelloWorld", "James", "Ted"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [object-dig package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-dig) :

> This allows you to use method like Ruby's hash#dig in JavaScript.

```
var dig = require('object-dig');

var object = { a: { b: { c: 'c' } } };

dig(object, 'a', 'b');
// => { c: 'c' } 

dig(object, 'a', 'b', 'c');
// => 'c' 

dig(object, 'a', 'unknownProp', 'c');
// =>undefined
```